# How to create directory in ITS

Tags: its

I am setting up an ITS system and am wondering how to create a directory. Google didn't help. Any really old farts here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a directory, use the following command:

```
^R <dirname>; ..new. (udir)<enter>
```

For example:

```
^R ejs;..new. (udir)<enter>
```